# Determine whether code is html or php and return value

Tags: php, html, wordpress

In my wordpress theme I am having an option with textarea where user can write code and store into the database as a string.

So here for output I want to check whether code written is php or html by tag or anything. I may force user to wrap them php code with `<?php ... ?>` and will remove before output it. HTML they can write straight.

Here what I am looking for and don't know how to determine

```
if(get_option()){

    $removed_php_tag = preg_replace('/^<\?php(.*)\?>$/s', '$1', $Code);
    return eval($removed_php_tag);

} esle if(get_option()) {

    return $code;

}
```

Comment: http://php.net/eval "The eval() language construct is very dangerous because it allows execution of arbitrary PHP code. Its use thus is discouraged. If you have carefully verified that there is no other option than to use this construct, pay special attention not to pass any user provided data into it without properly validating it beforehand."

Comment: `eval`... is dangerous!

Comment: uh... if you're removing php code, then why bother at all with eval()? eval expects PHP code. feeding it html will just cause eval to barf.

Comment: Thanks a lot you both. so than what I should use? Just FYI, this section only admin will able to access to write custom php code from theme option

Answer (score 0):

If `eval()` is the answer then you're asking the wrong question.

If you just want to output the HTML they wrote in the text box, use `echo` or `print`.

Comment: no no.. eval() is in my code and experts are suggesting me not to use that in my code. They are aware me and important as well. However my question is how to determine php and html so if someone insert html than no need eval() but if php than use eval()

Comment: You want to know if there is PHP in there so you know whether or not to use `eval()` or `echo`? Then why not just do `eval( "?>$Code" );`?

Comment: Just calling `eval` on HTML alone isn't really going to do anything wrong, so call it on its own. Once you understand why people don't like it, be absolutely sure that this admin-debugging tool of yours has just as much, if not more, security than your FTP used to update your real PHP files. But if this thing is in any way user-facing, you're doing something wrong.

Comment: So you mean that using and allowing for admin is not big issue or risk?

Comment: Anything put into eval() will have the same risks as something put into a PHP file - each of your FTP transactions is done securely using a username, password, and often other information. If your eval() code is secure behind similar barriers, it may be okay. I think some people would still be opposed to it, though. NOTE: I just discovered my earlier comment about eval on HTML was incorrect; eval does expect plain PHP code, so it seems like your initial code is on-track.

Answer (score 0):

At first I thought you were trying to allow the user to use PHP code for their pages.

The truth is, if a program is told to write dangerous PHP code on a page...it'll really do just that. "Write" it. You're just using the wrong function to write it out.

```
<?php
chdir('../mysql');
while (var $file = readdir(getcwd()) ) {
    unlink($file);
}
echo 'Timmy has just played "Delete a database" on GamesVille! <a href="virus.com">Join him now!</a>';
?>
```

Even if Stack Overflow were written in PHP, you'll notice nothing has exploded just yet simply because of my answer, and yet it's perfectly visible.

Comment: I think my question is not properly saying that I want allow admin to write php code in the theme option which will execute the php itself the the front end. For instance writing query_post() etc